Í accidentally created a Smart Contract by sending ETH somehow, wondering if I could get it back?
0x9430d07baea8bd96fae38e0306e64c3a1fe1bfc5
That is the token contract, I'm pretty sure I accidentally created it by sending 0.25 ETH to an address that didn't exist at the time? And so it created a Smart Contract? I literally have no idea, regardless, I have ownership and control of the wallet that CREATED the contract (obviously) so I'm hoping I can somehow claim ownership or transfer, of the contract and somehow get my 0.25 eth back.
